# Convert values into readable hours

Tags: javascript

I have this strings:

```
var case1 = '5.25 - 12.25, 13 - 18.5';
var case2 = '6.5 - 12, 13 - 18.5';
var case3 = '9 - 13, 14 - 18';
```

and I need to convert them to:

```
result1; //05:15 - 12:15, 13:00 - 18:30;
result2; //06:30 - 12:00, 13:00 - 18:30;
result3; //09:00 - 13:00, 14:00 - 18:00;
```

Is it possible to do only with regex?

Rules:

1) add leading 0 if the number is less than 10.
2) replace the `.25` with `:15` and the `.5` with `:30`
3) If there's nothing after the point, add `00`

I tried doing it with conditionals, replaces, etc but it's a mess.

Comment: with some of the answers your case strings will have to have a strict format, e.g. space after . or after - otherwise it will break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use one regular expression, but using the `replace` callback function:

```js
const cases = [
    '5.25 - 12.25, 13 - 18.5',
    '6.5 - 12, 13 - 18.5',
    '9 - 13, 14 - 18'
];

const result = cases.map( c => c.replace(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g, (_, h, m) => 
    ('0'+h).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + (Math.floor(m*60) || 0)).substr(-2)
));

console.log(result);
```

## ES5 syntax:

```js
var cases = [
    '5.25 - 12.25, 13 - 18.5',
    '6.5 - 12, 13 - 18.5',
    '9 - 13, 14 - 18'
];

var result = cases.map(function (c) {
    return c.replace(/(\d+)(\.\d+)?/g, function (_, h, m) { 
        return ('0'+h).substr(-2) + ':' + ('0' + (Math.floor(m*60) || 0)).substr(-2);
    });
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: trincot thanks this worked! Can you include example without ES6 though?

Answer (score 1):

A non regex solution:

```
const cases = [
  '5.25 - 12.25, 13 - 18.5',
  '6.5 - 12, 13 - 18.5',
  '9 - 13, 14 - 18'
];

const result = cases.map( c =>
   c.split(", ").map(range =>
      range.split(" - ").map(time => {
         const [hours,mins] = time.split(".");
         return ("00"+hours).substr(-2)+":"+(Math.floor( mins*6/10 ) || "00");
      }).join(" - ")
   ).join(", ")
);
```

[In action](http://jsbin.com/gaxiqaxuso/edit?console)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var cases = ['5.25 - 12.25, 13 - 18.5',
'6.5 - 12, 13 - 18.5',
'9 - 13, 14 - 18'];

cases.forEach(function(src){
  var times = src.replace(/([\d\.])+/g,function(match){
    var seconds = match*60;
    var minutes = parseInt(seconds/60);
    var seconds = "00" + seconds%60;
    seconds = seconds.substr(seconds.length-2);
    return minutes+":"+seconds;

  });  
  console.log(times);
});
```